# What is the best way to convert two columns of data to Julian dates in R?

Tags: r

I am very new at R and am trying to solve a data processing problem.  I have a dataframe with two date columns: Year and Julian Date.  The Julian Date column simply runs from 1-365.  I am attempting to combine both columns into one that puts data in the form of YYYY-MM-DD and so far have met with no success.  As_date did not appear to recognize Julian in a yearly format, and make_date returned NA values.  Has anyone seen this problem before and could help?  I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Taylor, please include some example data and, code you've tried, and your expected output. See the [Asking help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines, and specifically the section on using a minimum, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `chron`package. Suposse:

```
dat <- data.frame(jul= 120:122, yyyy = rep(2005, 3))
> dat
  jul yyyy
1 120 2005
2 121 2005
3 122 2005
```

Extract yyyymmdd values

```
 newDates <- as.data.frame(month.day.year(dat$jul, origin. = c(month = 1, day = 1, year = dat$yyyy)))

  month day year
1     5   1 2005
2     5   2 2005
3     5   3 2005
```

Generate your column with yyyy-mm-dd

```
dat$nwDt <- apply(newDates, 1, function(x) paste(x[3], x[1], x[3], sep = '-'))

> dat
 jul yyyy     nwDt
1 120 2005 2005-5-1
2 121 2005 2005-5-2
3 122 2005 2005-5-3
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the 120th day of the is not Feb. 5th.  Try>: as.Date(paste(dat$yyyy, dat$jul), format = '%Y %j')

Comment: Thanks. I inverted mont-day values.

Answer (score -1):

```
> my_date <- as.Date('2017-04-27')
> my_date
[1] "2017-04-27"
> 
> my_julian_date <- format(my_date,'%Y-%j' )
> my_julian_date
[1] "2017-117"
> 
> 
> my_j_d_char <- as.character(my_julian_date)
> my_j_d_char
[1] "2017-117"
> 
> my_date2 <- as.Date(my_j_d_char, format = '%Y-%j')
> my_date2
[1] "2017-04-27"
```

Comment: This seems to answer the inverse question.

Comment: actually I did it both ways, so the questions is answered.